# Simpson's rule error rate for N-dimension

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I'm doing a project that involves numerical method,
but I'm not too familiar on calculus.

I'm using Simpson's rule to integrate n-dimension gaussian, 
I was able to get the integration result for n-dimension,
but how do I get the error rate?

For 1-D, according to Wiki, it's simply
$$
\frac{1}{90} (b-a)^5 f''''(k)
$$

So, for 1-D, I can get
$$
f(x) = e^{-x^2}  
$$
$$
f''''(x) = 4(4x^4-12x^2+3) e^{-x^2}
$$

But how do I do this for example for 2-D?
$$
\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dx dy
$$

Thanks a lot for the help.